# Vaadin - com.vaadin.ui.Select - indentation

Tags: select, hierarchy, vaadin, indentation

I'm building vaadin select with hierarchical employees data (employee, subemployee), where max subemployee level is 6. I would like to display my data in select in hierarchical way for example:

```
Root Employee 1
    Subemployee 1.1
    Subemployee 1.2
    Subemployee 1.3
        Subemployee 1.3.1
        Subemployee 1.3.2
    Subemployee4
Root Employee 2
    Subemployee 2.1
        Subemployee 2.1.1
```

However when I'm adding a space by calling setItemCaption on my select it's being removed.
I have added "...." however then the filtering is not working properly, becouse the user is forced to enter "...." to find subemployees on level1. I have also tried with "\t", "\u0020", "&nbsp" but none of it worked.

Comment: Are you sure that `&nbsp;` doesn't work? Why don't you use vaadin Tree to display hierarchy?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that "&nbsp" doesn't work. I don't want to use vaadin tree to display hierarchy becouse the data should be presented in select/combobox.

Comment: And what about faking a combo box by displaying a panel with the tree over/below the dropdown when clicking on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your filtering problem, have you tried:

```
setFilteringMode(FilteringMode.CONTAINS);
```

Answer (score 1):

By default CSS property `white-space` is set to `nowrap` for select items. So, white spaces in item captions are rendered in html, but not displayed.

The way to workaround this issue is to override style for select items:

```
.v-filterselect-suggestpopup-myselect .v-filterselect-suggestmenu .gwt-MenuItem{
    white-space: pre;
}
```

then set needed style name to select:

```
mySelect.setStyleName("myselect");
```

Here I assumed that your question is about single-select mode (`ComboBox`). You can use the same approach (`white-space: pre;`) for multi-select mode (`ListSelect`) as well, but you'll need to use another matching rule.